# Some gitlab folders showing as submodules

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

Excuse the potentially naive question - I am not a software engineer by any means...

I am using .git to track revision changes for .xlsx files. I've created a git repo ("main" - hosted by Gitlab) - the folder structure is as follows:

- Main (.git repo)

  - _archive
  - _personal
  - pricing_model
  - inventory_model
  - monthly_close

When I commit and push the "main" folder, Gitlab picks up all the folders, but classifies **"pricing_model", "inventory_model", and "monthly_close" as submodules** [(see attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF8Uh.jpg). As a result, I cannot drill through Gitlab's interface to see the files that are within the submodule.

**QUESTIONS**

1. How do I configure my main folder so that I can drill through all subfolders?
2. Is "submodule" the correct terminology in this instance?

Comment: Are the submodules hosted on GitLab aswell?

Comment: I pushed the "main" folder to gitlab and the submodules are now shown in gitlab. However, I cannot access the files within these submodules through gitlab's interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, git supports a feature which is called *submodules* and it is basically a repository in a repository. That means if the repository doesn't exist on GitLab, you won't be able to browse trough it's contents.

If you want to browse trough those files in GitLab however, you would need to create a new Project for each of those submodules and push them on there. Then you could update the references in the `.gitmodules` file. Something like this for example:

```
[submodule "inventory"]
path = inventory
url = https://gitlab.com/<group>/<project>
branch = master


[submodule "monthly_close"]
path = pricing_model
url = https://gitlab.com/<group>/<project>
branch = master


[submodule "pricing_model"]
path = pricing_model
url = https://gitlab.com/<group>/<project>
branch = master
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, so will I have to create a .git file for each submodule?

I thought it was best-practice to just have 1 master .git file with subfolders. Am I mistaken?


Also, why isn't _personal and _archive treated as a submodule? I haven't created individual .git files for these folders, yet they're explorable through Gitlab's interface

Comment: Submodules are fully functional repositories in another repository. They are used if you have a dependency on another project for example. Since they are considered repositories, you need to push them to GitLab. What is the content of your .gitmodule file anyways?

Comment: `inventory` , `monthly_close` and `pricing_model` are already repositories (they should have a .git file in your project). They are defined as submodules in your `.gitmodules`. `_personal` and `_archive` are not considered submodules because they are not defined in the `.gitmodules` and are not repositories.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up.

While your method worked, I also just created new folders within the .git main folder and migrated my files into the new, working, subfolders.